# USB plug/unplug simulation under windows

Tags: controller, usb, driver

Does some one know if there's any way to simulate (by an calling an API) a plug or an unplug of an USB device while the device still physically plugged!?

The goal is to force loading/unloading the USB driver by software.

Another solution can be to power off the USB interface (to simulate unplug) and power it on (plug) again, this normally will trigger an interruption on the USB controller and start the proper enumeration (so driver loading) procedures.

Is there any API for doing that under Windows? Or is there any documentation somewhere?

Do you have another idea?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an API call to cycle a usb port. This is because the operation is a privileged operation that can have serious side effects for the device.

If you have your own driver, you can cycle the port by sending a [IOCTL_INTERNAL_USB_CYCLE_PORT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff537243%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) down the stack.

If you do not have access to the driver source, the hardware vendor may have an API in which they expose `CyclePort()` or `Reset()` functionality.